# Return in an if

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i was practice a kind of filter with a for and if, but i found an output without sense to me, can anyone clarify me the difference for the outputs? Thanks for your time

```js
function eg1(param) {
    sum=[]
    for (let i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
        let elements = param[i];
        if (elements>0) {
            return sum.push(elements)
        }
    } 
   return sum.length
}

function eg2(param) {
    sum=[]
    for (let i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
        let elements = param[i];
        if (elements>0) {
            sum.push(elements)
        // return sum.push(elements)
        }
    } 
   return sum.length
}
console.log(eg1([0,-3,1,5])) // 1
console.log(eg2([0,-3,1,5])) // 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array after adding the new elements, so if you uncomment `return sum.push(elements)`, the function will be returning the number of elements in `sum` after adding `elements` to it.

In your case, as `elements` is actually a single `number`, as long as you pass at least one number `> 0` it's always going to return `1`, as it will abort the `for` loop and return from that function as soon as it gets to the first one.

If you comment that line, then the `for` loop will actually go through all the values you pass in as `param` and return the number of elements inside `sum` once it's done.

Here you can follow the execution of both variations:

```js
function eg1(values) {
  const sum = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const value = values[i];
    
    console.log(`Checking value = ${ value }`);

    if (value > 0) {
      console.log(`  ${ value } > 0, so adding it to sum and returning from the function.`);
      
      return sum.push(value);
    }
  } 

  return sum.length;
}

function eg2(values) {
  const sum = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const value = values[i];
    
    console.log(`Checking value = ${ value }`);

    if (value > 0) {
      console.log(`  ${ value } > 0, so adding it to sum before checking the next one.`);
      
      sum.push(value);
    }
  } 

  return sum.length;
}

console.log('\nEG 1');
console.log('\nReturns', eg1([0, -3, 1, 5])); 
console.log('\nEG 2');
console.log('\nReturns', eg2([0, -3, 1, 5]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I would add that  the `return` statement shortcuts the for loop.

Comment: @dwjohnston Just added it a few more details about each scenario  

Answer (score 1):

You can see the output of below-given program. Once you return inside the for loop, it exits/return from the function `eg1`

```
1: after push> data: 1  elements: 1
1
2: after push> elements: 1
2: after push> elements: 5
2: will reach 
2
```

**Example:**

```js
function eg1(param) {
  let sum = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
    let elements = param[i];
    if (elements > 0) {
      const data = sum.push(elements);
      console.log(`1: after push> data: ${data}  elements: ${elements}`);
      return data;
    }
  }
  console.log("1: will not reach ");
  return sum.length;
}

function eg2(param) {
  sum = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
    let elements = param[i];
    if (elements > 0) {
      sum.push(elements);
      console.log(`2: after push> elements: ${elements}`);
    }
  }
  console.log("2: will reach ");
  return sum.length;
}
console.log(eg1([0, -3, 1, 5])); // 1
console.log(eg2([0, -3, 1, 5])); // 2
```